# jquery load unload not working on samsung browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JQuery code on my webpage, which watches for page load unload events and invokes functions accordingly, but I notice that although these work on chrome, safari, firefox, they dont work on Samsung browsers. So, I have the following:

```
var isOnIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
var isOnSamsung=navigator.userAgent.match(/SAMSUNG|Samsung|SGH-[I|N|T]|GT-[I|N]|SM-[A|N|P|T|Z]|SHV-E|SCH-[I|J|R|S]|SPH-L/i);
var eventName_unload = isOnIOS ? "pagehide" 
                        : isOnSamsung ? "unload" 
                        : "unload";
var eventName_load = isOnIOS ? "pageshow" 
                        : isOnSamsung ? "load" 
                        : "load";
```

and the JQuery:

```
$(window).on(eventName_load, function() {var test=clearStuff(); });
```

`iOS` and default works fine (load, unload, pageshow, pagehide) but the Samsung ones do not.

Any clues as to why this is would be great.

Comment: um, jquery should never have "on" in the event handlers. So why is it addding "onunload" for the browser that is not working?

Comment: @epascarello: I have corrected the question now, but it does not seem to solve the problem - I am not sure the load and unload are supported in smsung browser..

Comment: Seems very strange that window.onload would not be supported in a browser. Maybe it is a different issue.

Comment: @epascarello: the thing is it works perfectly well on all browsers on desktops and firefox, chrome and safari on mobile. Would be nice if it also works on samsung browser.

Comment: Debug and figure out what is not working. Are you sure the event is not being called? Or is it the function `clearStuff` not actually working.

Comment: @epascarello: the function works, I have checked it on ALL browsers on desktop and mobile.. it is ONLY the samsung browser which does not.. Assuming my phone browser is out of date, I even tried browserstack.. and even here, it works on every browser EXCEPT samsung!